# Passing DHT22 output in Python to PHP

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, sensors, gpio

I have a DHT22 Temperature and Humidity sensor connected to my Raspberry Pi.  When running my Python script via CLI, the script works as expected and displays the temperature and humidity readings.  The problem that I am having is that I cannot retrieve the sensor output via PHP.

As a test, I've included a command to print "Hello World" within my Python script.  When I load my PHP page, "Hello World" is displayed, the output from the sensor is not displayed.

Per some of the discussions that I have read when troubleshooting this issue, the owner and group of my Python script is "www-data" and this user has been added to the sudoers file on my webserver.

Any guidance is appreciated.  I've been at this for quite some time without any breakthroughs and suspect my unfamiliarity with Python may be the source of my problem.

read_dht.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Copyright (c) 2014 Adafruit Industries
# Author: Tony DiCola
print 'Hello World...'

import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
pin = 4

humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)

if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
   print '{0:0.1f}|{1:0.1f}'.format(temperature, humidity)
else:
   print 'Failed to get a reading. Please try again!'
```

get_readings.php

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('/var/www/cgi-bin/read_dht.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: If you want to expose your service on Internet or public network, it is generally a (very) bad idea to add www-data to sudoers. The idea of having a www-data user is to avoid attacker to get root rights in case of php vulnerability. If you add www-data to sudoers, you will not have this privilege separation! (i.e. it's as if you were running your apache/php in root..)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup access to GPIO on Raspberry PI otherwise it will only be accessible for root.

Try to run the following code **as root in a terminal** and then check the output from your PHP script using your browser:

```
echo "17" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "18" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "21" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "22" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "23" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "24" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "25" > /sys/class/gpio/export

echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio21/direction
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio22/direction
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/direction
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio24/direction
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio25/direction

chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value
chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio21/value
chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio22/value
chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value
chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio24/value
chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio25/value

chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction
chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio21/direction
chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio22/direction
chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/direction
chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio24/direction
chmod 666 /sys/class/gpio/gpio25/direction
```